# I want to hook win32API CreateFileW by detours and print callstack information captured by CaptureStackBackTrace

Tags: c++, winapi, callstack, detours

I use detours to hook win32 api CreateFile and use CaptureStackBackTrace to get callstack information. and then resolve symbol by SymFromAddr api. but the result shown in terminal is    only error 126 and error 184. And I only invoke ShowTraceStack function one time while trace information is more than one. I do not know what happened, can someone help me?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "detours.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib")  //Windows API   PathFileExists
#include <io.h>   
#pragma comment(lib, "detours.lib")
#include <DbgHelp.h>                    //SymInitialize
#pragma comment(lib,"dbghelp.lib")
#define STACK_INFO_LEN  20000

struct stackInfo {
    PDWORD hashValue; // hash value to identify same stack
    char* szBriefInfo; // callstack info
};
stackInfo ShowTraceStack(char* szBriefInfo)
{
    static const int MAX_STACK_FRAMES = 200;
    void* pStack[MAX_STACK_FRAMES];
    static char szStackInfo[STACK_INFO_LEN * MAX_STACK_FRAMES];
    static char szFrameInfo[STACK_INFO_LEN];

    HANDLE process = GetCurrentProcess(); // The handle used must be unique to avoid sharing a session with another component,
    SymInitialize(process, NULL, TRUE);
    PDWORD hashValue = (PDWORD)malloc(sizeof(DWORD)); // allow memory for hashVavlue, it will be rewrited in function CaptureStackBackTrace
    WORD frames = CaptureStackBackTrace(0, MAX_STACK_FRAMES, pStack, hashValue);
    //printf("hash value is: %ud \n", &hashValue);
    if (szBriefInfo == NULL) {
        strcpy_s(szStackInfo, "stack traceback:\n");
    }
    else {
        strcpy_s(szStackInfo, szBriefInfo);
    }

    for (WORD i = 0; i < frames; ++i) {
        DWORD64 address = (DWORD64)(pStack[i]);

        DWORD64 displacementSym = 0;
        char buffer[sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + MAX_SYM_NAME * sizeof(TCHAR)];
        PSYMBOL_INFO pSymbol = (PSYMBOL_INFO)buffer;
        pSymbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);
        pSymbol->MaxNameLen = MAX_SYM_NAME;

        DWORD displacementLine = 0;
        IMAGEHLP_LINE64 line;
        line.SizeOfStruct = sizeof(IMAGEHLP_LINE64);

        if (SymFromAddr(process, address, &displacementSym, pSymbol) &&
            SymGetLineFromAddr64(process, address, &displacementLine, &line))
        {
            _snprintf_s(szFrameInfo, sizeof(szFrameInfo), "\t%s() at %s:%d(0x%x)\n",
                pSymbol->Name, line.FileName, line.LineNumber, pSymbol->Address);
        }
        else
        {
            _snprintf_s(szFrameInfo, sizeof(szFrameInfo), "\terror: %d\n", GetLastError());
        }
        strcat_s(szStackInfo, szFrameInfo);
    }
    stackInfo traceStackInfo;
    traceStackInfo.hashValue = hashValue;
    traceStackInfo.szBriefInfo = szStackInfo;
    printf("%s", szStackInfo); 

    return traceStackInfo;
}
HANDLE(*oldCreateFile)(LPCWSTR,
    DWORD,
    DWORD,
    LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,
    DWORD,
    DWORD,
    HANDLE) = CreateFileW;

HANDLE WINAPI newCreateFile(
    _In_ LPCWSTR lpFileName,
    _In_ DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
    _In_ DWORD dwShareMode,
    _In_opt_ LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
    _In_ DWORD dwCreationDisposition,
    _In_ DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    _In_opt_ HANDLE hTemplateFile
) {
    ShowTraceStack((char*)"trace information.");
    return oldCreateFile(
        L".\\newFiles.txt", // L".\\NewFile.txt",     // Filename
        //lpFileName,
        dwDesiredAccess,          // Desired access
        dwShareMode,        // Share mode
        lpSecurityAttributes,                   // Security attributes
        dwCreationDisposition,             // Creates a new file, only if it doesn't already exist
        dwFlagsAndAttributes,  // Flags and attributes
        NULL);
}

void hook() {
    DetourRestoreAfterWith();
    DetourTransactionBegin();
    DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
    DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)oldCreateFile, newCreateFile);
    DetourTransactionCommit();
}

void unhook()
{
    DetourTransactionBegin();
    DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
    DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)oldCreateFile, newCreateFile);
    DetourTransactionCommit();
}

void myProcess() {
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(TEXT(".\\CreateFileDemo.txt"),    
        GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,          
        0,                      
        NULL,                   
        CREATE_ALWAYS,          
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,        
        NULL);                
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        OutputDebugString(TEXT("CreateFile fail!\r\n"));
    }

    // write to file 
    const int BUFSIZE = 4096;
    char chBuffer[BUFSIZE];
    memcpy(chBuffer, "Test", 4);
    DWORD dwWritenSize = 0;
    BOOL bRet = WriteFile(hFile, chBuffer, 4, &dwWritenSize, NULL);
    ShowTraceStack((char*)"trace information.");  

    if (bRet)
    {
        OutputDebugString(TEXT("WriteFile success!\r\n"));
    }

}

int main(){
  
    hook();

    myProcess();

    unhook();
}
```

[image]

Comment: 487 == Attempt to access invalid address.

Comment: 126 == The specified module could not be found.

Comment: It's unknown if your `GetLastError()` call is capturing the error from `SymFromAddr`, `SymGetLineFromAddr64`, or the printf call itself. Always call GetLastError (and save the result) **immediately** after making an API call.

Comment: Note, `oldCreateFile`'s signature is missing the `WINAPI` (aka `__stdcall`) calling convention. Calling convention mismatches can cause very nasty runtime errors.

Comment: @sel *"It's unknown if your `GetLastError()` call is capturing the error from [...] the printf call itself."* - Arguments are evaluated prior to making the call. The value returned from `GetLastError()` cannot be a side effect from the `printf` call.

Comment: yeap, thanks for your reply. the error 126 and 487 is captured from SymFromAddr, SymGetLineFromAddr64. i modified my code to show where errors are com from. The error 126 is generated by SymFromAddr and error 487 is generated by SymGetLineFromAddr64. do you know the reason why produce those error? and why i only invoke ShowStack() one time, but get the number of callstack infomation more than one .